# Can I find these parameters to make this fourth degree polynomial has a single real root?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

The polynomial is defined as:

$$
P(X)=\left(1+\left(\alpha+X\right)^2\right)\left(1+\left(\beta-X\right)^2\right)-\Delta.
$$

Can I find positive $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\Delta$ to make $P(X)=0\iff X=A$ for some $A$? $P(X)$ will be $P(X)=\left(X-A\right)^4$

EDIT:

In other words, how to solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\Delta$ this system of non-linear equalities.

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
2A = \beta-\alpha\\
6A^2=\beta^2+2-4\alpha\beta+\alpha^2\\
-4A^3=2\alpha\beta^2+2\alpha-2\beta-2\beta\alpha^2\\
A^4=1+\beta^2+\alpha^2+\alpha^2\beta^2-\Delta
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $x:={\beta-\alpha\over2}+y$. Then your polynomial $P$ will assume the form
$$q(y)=A+By^2+y^4\tag{1}$$
with
$$B={1\over2}\bigl(4-(\alpha+\beta)^2\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that choosing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $|\alpha+\beta|\leq2$ will guarantee that $q$ has a unique global minimum at $y=0$. Now choose $\Delta$ such that in $(1)$ we have $A=0$ as well.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I found $\alpha=-A+1,\beta=A+1,\Delta=4$ and $\alpha=-A-1,\beta=A-1,\Delta=4$ the only solutions.